# Calculate Volume of Ball in d-dimensional space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to show that 
$p( \left\lVert x \right\rVert_p \leq \alpha R) = vol(B_p^d(\alpha R))/ 
 vol(B_p^d(R))$

Where

$B_p^d(R) = {y \in (y_1, ...., y_n} \in R^d : \left\lVert y \right\rVert_p \leq R$ }

and

$0 \leq \alpha \leq 1 $ and x is drawn randomly and uniformly from $B_p^d(R)$

I know it's intuitive but I cannot put that into a mathematical form. I've tried to use the integration to show that but I cannot show integration for d-dimensional ball.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that ${\rm vol}$ and "uniformly" refer to euclidean measure in ${\mathbb R}^d$, whereas the body
$$B_p(R):=\bigl\{y\in{\mathbb R}^d\bigm||y_1|^p+\ldots+|y_d|^p\leq R^p\bigr\}$$ is the ball of radius $R$ with repect to the $p$-norm in ${\mathbb R}^d$. If the random point $X$ is "distributed uniformly" in $B_p(R)$ then by definition
$$p\bigl( \|X\|_p\leq\alpha R\bigr)={{\rm vol}\bigl(B_p(\alpha R)\bigr)\over{\rm vol}\bigl(B_p(R)\bigr)}=\alpha^d\ ,$$
whereby the second = comes from the similarity of the balls in question. (Note that a linear scaling $T$ by the factor $\alpha\geq0$ multiplies volumes by ${\rm det}(T)=\alpha^d$.)

If ${\rm vol}$  refers to the measure on ${\mathbb R}^d$ induced by the $p$-norm one would first have to think about the appearance of this measure in terms of the coordinates in ${\mathbb R}^d$. At any rate I conjecture that the probability you want to compute remains the same, namely $\alpha^d$.

Comment: Ok this shows that most left side is equal to the most right but I think it doesn't show how volumes are related in terms of volume definition like relating the radius  probably. Also can you guide me into more in that where can I find and practice similar problems. Thanks